# Any way to add a 3rd level menu item in AdminLTE sidebar?

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I'm trying to find a way to have 3rd level menus in the side bar for my AdminLTE (V3.1.0) portal. Basically i'm trying to achieve something like below:

```
<ul id="sidebarTree" class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="true">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-address-book"></i>
        <p>
            LEVEL 1 ITEM
            <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </p>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="level2item">
                <i class="nav-icon far fa-circle"></i>
                <p>LEVEL 2 ITEM/p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-address-book"></i>
            <p>
                LEVEL 2 ITEM - EXPANDABLE
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </p>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="level3item">
                    <i class="nav-icon far fa-circle"></i>
                    <p>LEVEL 3 ITEM/p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done? Or can this even be done at all?

See here (https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1//components/main-sidebar.html) for how the sidebar looks like in their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, all you have to do is add the class name `nav-item` to the parent `li`.

```css
li > ul {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1//assets/css/adminlte.min.css">
<ul id="sidebarTree" class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="true">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-address-book"></i>
        <p>
            LEVEL 1 ITEM
            <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </p>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="level2item">
                <i class="nav-icon far fa-circle"></i>
                <p>LEVEL 2 ITEM</p>
            </a>
        </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-address-book"></i>
            <p>
                LEVEL 2 ITEM - EXPANDABLE
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </p>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="level3item">
                    <i class="nav-icon far fa-circle"></i>
                    <p>LEVEL 3 ITEM</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/docs/3.1//assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/docs/3.1//assets/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Stackoverflow restricts some imports here you can view it in my codepen below

Working example here:  https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/rNzOoob